# Moving duplicate numbers to end of an array

Tags: java, methods

I need to do a method for calculate smallStraight in Yahtzee (small straight means you have 4 die that increase by one.. for examples, `1,2,3,4,6` is a small straight). Now I'm trying to get over the hurdle that when you sort an Array, there could be duplicate numbers.
For example, if you roll and then sort, you may get a `1, 2, 2, 3, 4`. Now I basically need to remove the second 2 to the end of the Array. Here is my code. Note, this obviously doesn't work regarding the nested four loops. I just want to know the best way to go about this.

```
public int setSmallStraight(int[] die)
{
    if (!isSmallStraightUsed)
    {
      int counter = 0;
      boolean found = false;
      Arrays.sort(die);

      for (int i = 0; i < die.length - 1; i++)
      {
          if (counter == 3)
              found = true;

          if (die[i + 1] == die[i] + 1)
          {
              counter++;
          }
          else if (die[i + 1] == die[i])
          {
              continue;
          }
          else
          {
              counter = 0;
          }
      }

      if (found)
      {
         smallStraight = 30; 
      }
      else
      {
          smallStraight = 0;
      }
      return smallStraight;
    }
   else
        return 0;
   }
```

Comment: How does the custom sorting actually help in your specific situation? I'd recommend trying to avoid the need to do this to your data except perhaps at display time

Comment: You could create a new array (or list) by completely removing the duplicates after sorting.

Comment: I also suggest that you use the input list directly rather than copying it into an array. You can make a copy of the list and sort it and otherwise manipulate it as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What about having a `int counter` that counts the number of consecutive `+1` increases in your array? Something like that:

```
public boolean hasSmallStraight(int[] sortedValues) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<sortedValues.length-1; i++) {
        if (counter == 3) return true;

        if (sortedValues[i+1] == sortedValues[i] + 1) {
            counter++;
        } else if (sortedValues[i+1] == sortedValues[i]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    return counter==3;
}
```

Note: this only works for small straights

Comment: How about if I want to make this method int instead of boolean? Instead of "return true" should I put: "smallStraight = 20" and then instead of return counter == 3. put "return smallStraight?"

Comment: Are you talking about scoring? If so just do if (hasSmallStraight(dice)) {score += 30;}

Comment: Thanks. This sometimes works. Like, when I roll at 1, 3, 2, 6, 4 it will work. But if I roll a 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, it will not work. I think it has something to do with the duplicates I was having trouble with earlier. Unless I was supposed to sort the Array to begin with? EDIT: Nevermind, I sorted and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Just tried and {1,2,2,3,4} returns true for me so what's the issue? And yes, you need to sort the array first

Comment: Tried it again, and it didn't work. Let me try putting my code in the edit up at the top. Maybe I just made it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Integer[] items = {0, 4, 2, 2, 10, 5, 5, 5, 2};
System.out.println(customSort(Arrays.asList(items)));
}

public static Collection<Integer> customSort(List<Integer> die) {
Collections.sort(die);
Stack<Integer> numbas = new Stack<Integer>();
List<Integer> dupes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
numbas.push(die.get(0));
for (int i = 1; i < die.size(); i++) {
    if (!die.get(i).equals(numbas.peek())) {
    numbas.push(die.get(i));
    } else {
    dupes.add(die.get(i));
    }
}
numbas.addAll(dupes);
return numbas;
}
```

This yields the output

```
[0, 2, 4, 5, 10, 2, 2, 5, 5]
```

Add error checking and handling as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is sorted, you can use an algorithm like below. Please read the comment I've put, hopefully it clearly explains how it works. Also as precaution -- this is by no means most efficient implementation, so if your array is huge consider the performance.

```
// Sequentially iterate array using 2 indices: i & j
// Initially i points to 1st element, j point to 2nd element
// The assumption is there's at least 2 element in the array.
// 'end' acts as a boundary limit to which element hasn't been checked
for(int i=0,j=1,end=array.length; j<end; ) {

    // If element pointed by i & j are equal, shift element pointed
    // by j to the end. Decrement the end index so we don't test element
    // that's already shifted to the back.
    // Also in this case we don't increment i & j because after shifting we
    // want to perform the check at the same location again (j would have pointed
    // to the next element)
    if(array[i] == array[j]) {

        // This for loop shifts element at j to the back of array
        for(int k=j; k<array.length-1; k++) {
            int tmp = array[k+1];
            array[k+1] = array[k];
            array[k] = tmp;
        }

        end--;

    // if element at i and j are not equal, check the next ones
    } else {
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will completely remove the duplicates instead of simply moving them to the end of the list...

Comment: Ah sorry didn't realize OP just wanted to shift the duplicate to the end.. will modify my answer

Comment: I'm just in a beginning programming class, so we can't use a for loop like that. Is there any way to use two different for loops for that?

Comment: Edited my answer to use simple plain array (hence the necessity to use nested for loop)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4 };
    int[] a2 = new int[a1.length];
    int j = 0, k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length - 1; i++) {
        if (a1[i + 1] == a1[j]) {
            a2[k++] = a1[i + 1];
        } else {
            a1[++j] = a1[i + 1];
        }
    }
    System.arraycopy(a2, 0, a1, j + 1, k);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```